# calculating molecular weight in perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl script but it calculate molecular weight only when sequence is given. However I want to calculate molecular weight of protein sequences which is in fasta file.

```
print "Enter the amino acid sequence:\n";  
$a = < STDIN > ; 
chomp($a);
my @a = ();
my $a = '';
$x = length($a); 
print "Length of sequence is : $x";
@a = split('', $a); 
$b = 0; 
my %data = ( 
    A=>71.09,  R=>16.19,  D=>114.11,  N=>115.09, 
    C=>103.15,  E=>129.12,  Q=>128.14,  G=>57.05, 
    H=>137.14,  I=>113.16,  L=>113.16,  K=>128.17, 
    M=>131.19,  F=>147.18,  P=>97.12,  S=>87.08, 
    T=>101.11,  W=>186.12,  Y=>163.18,  V=>99.14 
); 
foreach $i(@a) { 
    $b += $data{$i}; 
} 
$c = $b - (18 * ($x - 1)); 
print "\nThe molecular weight of the sequence is $c";
```

Comment: You might want to format your code a little better to help us read it. Check out how to here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this help also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748858/reading-fasta-sequences-to-extract-nucleotide-data-and-then-writing-to-a-tabde ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i want my perl script to read protein sequences from a fasta file which in turn having many protein sequences and then calculate molecular weight of each protein sequences.

Comment: @PP.: Here, `@a` and `$a` are array and scalar views of the same data, since `@a = split ('', $a)`. I often use the same name in such circumstances. Why does it frustrate and anger you?

Comment: @PP.: If you find it confusing that Perl uses `$` for array elements, then I think your problem is with Perl 5, rather than with the programmers who write code in it. (Incidentally, you are not alone in your confusion, and as a result, Perl 6 uses `@` instead.) I agree that single-letter variables are bad; I was only replying to your point about using the same name for corresponding variables of different types.

Comment: @PP.: I don't understand why you keep talking about single-letter variables. Do you really not recognize that that's a separate issue?

Comment: Instead of arguing could you please sort out my problem....I describe the problem. You guys are independent of working on this issue. @PP: can you make another program solving my problem.

Comment: @Rulakh: could you please guide me what problem m I facing in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all u must tell us what format has .fasta files. As i know they looks like

```
>seq_ID_1 descriptions etc 
ASDGDSAHSAHASDFRHGSDHSDGEWTSHSDHDSHFSDGSGASGADGHHAH
ASDSADGDASHDASHSAREWAWGDASHASGASGASGSDGASDGDSAHSHAS
SFASGDASGDSSDFDSFSDFSD

>seq_ID_2 descriptions etc
ASDGDSAHSAHASDFRHGSDHSDGEWTSHSDHDSHFSDGSGASGADGHHAH
ASDSADGDASHDASHSAREWAWGDASHASGASGASG
```

if we will make suggestion that your code works fine, and counts molecular weight all we need is to read fasta files, parse them and count weight by yours code. It's more easy that sounds like.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;


for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file;
    my $input = join q{}, <$fh>; 
    close $fh;
    while ( $input =~ /^(>.*?)$([^>]*)/smxg ) {
        my $name = $1;
        my $seq = $2;
        $seq =~ s/\n//smxg;
        my $mass = calc_mass($seq);
        print "$name has mass $mass\n";
    }
}

sub calc_mass {
    my $a = shift;
    my @a = ();
    my $x = length $a;
    @a = split q{}, $a;
    my $b = 0;
    my %data = (
        A=>71.09,  R=>16.19,  D=>114.11,  N=>115.09,
        C=>103.15,  E=>129.12,  Q=>128.14,  G=>57.05,
        H=>137.14,  I=>113.16,  L=>113.16,  K=>128.17,
        M=>131.19,  F=>147.18,  P=>97.12,  S=>87.08,
        T=>101.11,  W=>186.12,  Y=>163.18,  V=>99.14
    );
    for my $i( @a ) {
        $b += $data{$i};
    }
    my $c = $b - (18 * ($x - 1));
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: so if i include your code with my perl script then it will do what i need

Comment: one more thing...my perl script is taking amino acid sequence through <stdin> but i need script to read from file

Comment: this code reads sequences from file. usage: `perl /path/to/script.pl /path/to/input.file /path/to/other.file`

Comment: should I merge your code with my script or use your code independently

Comment: cmon, man:) take a look at my code) your code is already integrated into it, and ready to use. just copy it to empty script and run it `perl /path/to/script.pl /path/to/input.file /path/to/other.file`

Comment: wrong file name or path. or you can't read this file, check file permissions

Comment: i simply write command "perl script.pl" (note: commas are not included) as I use active perl package

Comment: you need to write input file name after script.pl

Comment: like this "perl script.pl M.xanthum_protein_files.fasta"

Comment: I have a Perl script to calculate isoelectric point of fasta sequences however I don't get any output.