# How to fix the error of "Use of unitialized value in addition..." in perl script?

Tags: perl

Here is the script of user Suic for calculating molecular weight of fasta sequences ([calculating molecular weight in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563032/calculating-molecular-weight-in-perl)),

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;


for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file;
    my $input = join q{}, <$fh>; 
    close $fh;
    while ( $input =~ /^(>.*?)$([^>]*)/smxg ) {
        my $name = $1;
        my $seq = $2;
        $seq =~ s/\n//smxg;
        my $mass = calc_mass($seq);
        print "$name has mass $mass\n";
    }
}

sub calc_mass {
    my $a = shift;
    my @a = ();
    my $x = length $a;
    @a = split q{}, $a;
    my $b = 0;
    my %data = (
        A=>71.09,  R=>16.19,  D=>114.11,  N=>115.09,
        C=>103.15,  E=>129.12,  Q=>128.14,  G=>57.05,
        H=>137.14,  I=>113.16,  L=>113.16,  K=>128.17,
        M=>131.19,  F=>147.18,  P=>97.12,  S=>87.08,
        T=>101.11,  W=>186.12,  Y=>163.18,  V=>99.14
    );
    for my $i( @a ) {
        $b += $data{$i};
    }
    my $c = $b - (18 * ($x - 1));
    return $c;
}
```

and the protein.fasta file with n (here is 2) sequences:

> seq_ID_1 descriptions etc 
>       ASDGDSAHSAHASDFRHGSDHSDGEWTSHSDHDSHFSDGSGASGADGHHAH
>       ASDSADGDASHDASHSAREWAWGDASHASGASGASGSDGASDGDSAHSHAS
>       SFASGDASGDSSDFDSFSDFSD

```
>seq_ID_2 descriptions etc
ASDGDSAHSAHASDFRHGSDHSDGEWTSHSDHDSHFSDGSGASGADGHHAH
ASDSADGDASHDASHSAREWAWGDASHASGASGASG
```

When using: perl molecular_weight.pl protein.fasta > output.txt
in terminal, it will generate the correct results, however it also presents an error of "Use of unitialized value in addition (+) at molecular_weight.pl line36", which is just localized in line of "$b += $data{$i};" how to fix this bug ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: While BOM (byte order marker) isn't required in UTF-8 files, it can be there. I'd suggest doing. `$input =~ s/^\x{FEFF}//;` before you start processing it.

Comment: It means `$data{$i}` is `undef`, probably because `$i` isn't one of the values you expect.

Comment: I don't get the error - the program works flawlessly (as long as the expected result is 6798.62). Have you copy-pasted here? And what platform, and what version of Perl are you using? (I'm on Win 10 + Strawberry Perl v5.24.0).

Comment: @Silvar, I changed the $input =~ s/^\x{FEFF}// as you said, yes, no errors occured but no results too. I use perl 5.18.2 on ubuntu, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an errant SPACE somewhere in your data file. Just change

```
$seq =~ s/\n//smxg;
```

into

```
$seq =~ s/\s//smxg;
```

---

EDIT:

Besides whitespace, there may be some non-whitespace invisible characters in the data, like WORD JOINER (U+2060).

If you want to be sure to be thorough and you know all the legal symbols, you can delete everything apart from them:

```
$seq =~ s/[^ARDNCEQGHILKMFPSTWYV]//smxg;
```

Or, to make sure you won't miss any (even if you later change the symbols), you can populate a filter regex dynamically from the hash keys.

You'd need to make `%Data` and the filter regex global, so the filter is available in the main loop. As a beneficial side effect, you don't need to re-initialize the data hash every time you enter `calc_mass()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Data = (A=>71.09,...);
my $Filter_regex = eval { my $x = '[^' . join('', keys %Data) . ']'; qr/$x/; };

...

$seq =~ s/$Filter_regex//smxg;
```

(This filter works as long as the symbols are single character. For more complicated ones, it may be preferable to match for the symbols and collect them from the sequence, instead of removing unwanted characters.)

Comment: yes, you are right, when changed as you said, no error hint suggested in this case. while in some fasta file, it still give the error hint, so I delete the fasta sequences one by one, and I found one 'special' sequence, which still gives the error using the corrected script as you said, but when you copy to somewhere and back, you will find no error hint suggested. So, I think your solution is may solve some cases as you said, other strange cases still remaind.Thank you very much!

Comment: @james I've added to the solution.

Comment: Excellent !  your solutions really work ! Thank you very much!