# Perl program printing full .fasta file sequences to file, but trying to achieve specific nucleotide count with respect to genes

Tags: perl, tabs, bioinformatics, fasta

So far I've managed to gain a bit more of an understanding of Perl, which is a relief and I have you guys to thank. I'm currently still working on another aspect where I need to read a .fasta file and find all the G and C nucleotides and then create a tab-delimited file.

These were my posts over the past few days, in chronological order:

1. [How do I average column values from a tab-separated data...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677533/how-do-i-average-column-values-from-a-tab-separated-data-file-ignoring-a-header) **(Solved)**
2. [Why do I see no computed results in my output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716629/why-do-i-see-no-computed-results-in-my-output-file) **(Solved)**
3. [Using a .fasta file to compute relative content of sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716991/using-a-fasta-file-to-compute-relative-content-of-sequences)
4. [Reading .fasta sequences to extract nucleotide data, and then...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748858/reading-fasta-sequences-to-extract-nucleotide-data-and-then-writing-to-a-tabde) ***(Post preceding this one)***

The last query is still being worked upon but I have made some progress.

Some background, the .fasta file reads something like this:

```
>label
sequence
>label
sequence
>label
sequence
```

I'm unsure how to open the .fasta file, so I'm not sure what labels apply to which, but I know that the genes should be labelled either `gag`, `pol`, or `env`. Do I need to open the .fasta file to know what I'm doing, or can I do it 'blindly' by going with the above format?

Anyway, the current code I have is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# This script reads several sequences and computes the relative content of G+C of each sequence.

use strict; 

my $infile = "Lab1_seq.fasta";                               # This is the file path
open INFILE, $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!";        # This opens file, but if file isn't there it mentions this will not open
my $outfile = "Lab1_SeqOutput.txt";             # This is the file's output
open OUTFILE, ">$outfile" or die "Cannot open $outfile: $!"; # This opens the output file, otherwise it mentions this will not open

my $sequence = ();  # This sequence variable stores the sequences from the .fasta file
my $GC = 0;         # This variable checks for G + C content

my $line;                             # This reads the input file one-line-at-a-time

while ($line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp $line;                      # This removes "\n" at the end of each line (this is invisible)

    if($line =~ /^\s*$/) {         # This finds lines with whitespaces from the beginning to the ending of the sequence. Removes blank line.
        next;

    } elsif($line =~ qr(^\s*\#/)) {        # This finds lines with spaces before the hash character. Removes .fasta comment
        next; 
    } elsif($line =~ /^>/) {           # This finds lines with the '>' symbol at beginning of label. Removes .fasta label
        next;
    } else {
        $sequence = $line;
    }

    $sequence =~ s/\s//g;               # Whitespace characters are removed
    print OUTFILE $sequence;
}
```

The code now prints to text file the entire sequence with no whitespaces. The only problem is, I don't know where the sequences started or ended, so I'm unsure what sequences apply to each gene. Although a stop/start codon should give me an indication. With that taken into account, how would I modify/add to the code to calculate the amount of G+C in the sequences, and then print them to a tab-delimited file with names of the genes associated with their respective G/C content?

I look forward to hearing from someone who can provide some guidance, in a similar vein to the code posted above, with respect to how to find G/C and then tabulating the respective counts.

Answer (score 2):

The following links may be helpful. There is a lot of code already written, and [Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/SeqIO.pm) and [Bio::Seq](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=Bio%3a%3aSeq) seem to be discussed often. There is a web site for [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page) but I'm not familiar with it. There are code examples and other information there. The [FAQ](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/FAQ) is also helpful.

Here is a sample from the Bio::SeqIO documentation.

```
use Bio::SeqIO;

$in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => "inputfilename" ,
                       -format => 'Fasta');
$out = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">outputfilename" ,
                       -format => 'EMBL');

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
        $out->write_seq($seq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually work with [FASTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) files myself. So, I feel your pain.

To answer your repeated question about the applicability of labels to each sequence: each label preceding the sequence information should be for the sequence that follows if the file is formatted correctly. Thus, you should parse the file from the beginning to the end as follows:

```
>label1
sequence1
>label2
sequence2
>label3
sequence3
...
```

... where each label indicates new sequence information is to follow. You'll also want to ignore lines that begin with a semicolon (`;`), as these also indicate legacy comment fields.

Otherwise, you appear to be removing whitespace properly when reflowing the file. I would recommend keeping the label fields intact with a line break, so your output file looks like the above-noted format with comments and whitespace removed.

Once you have this, it's a simple matter of walking the reflowed file, grabbing the sequence pieces you need and restarting a counter whenever you encounter a new label.

Comment: How would you recommended going about that. Should I remove the 'if' line (which is labelled as removing the blank line)? I'm also trying to set up this counter as I need G+C from each of the 3 labels... Finding difficulty with this.

Comment: @PkC I recommend writing back the label when you detect it, adding an extra `\n` when you perform the write. That way, you get the sequences with their labeling structure intact and can continue forward to other operations. Best of luck to you with this.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of this? I keep getting some argument error returnings, which say that the values "aren't numeric" etc.

Comment: @PkC Yes, but not a satisfactory one in Perl as I have minimal experience in this language. If you're fluent in other languages like C++, I've constructed a parsing library for FASTA files as part of my project here: http://code.google.com/p/molotov/. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Not to worry. I'm going to hammer away at this until tomorrow. So far I've completed 2 out of 3 tasks. It had to be perl that was the 'lesser likely' programming language, at least from what I hear. I am very grateful for your help though! Thank you.